# How to hide development work from a not so trustworthy fellow farm admin or site admin?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

Unfortunately there are some unfriend-lies out there even in your own circle who doesn't mean your work or progress well. Sometimes even a service account has been used to peer in and worse.
Is there a way to hide/safeguard dev work ( SP 2010 Workflows, sub-sites and InfoPath forms ) only meant for me to finish , away from those folks ( in any shape or manner without breaking paths too much ) before completion and unveiling .

Comment: If  someone has access to a service-account, they would in theory be able to access anything. If you have someone ruining your stuff, you should get to the bottom with the actual problem. Or you could make it a habbit to backup your site collection often where you develop stuff so you know that you always have a backup of your work if anything "would happen".

Comment: Thank you Jussi you are right however are there any tricks to make your work a little more covert? The problem leaves me to find a solution for myself since the Admin is the Manager's "favorite" and because of it he abuses his authority. Doesn't leave much for me to after I approached and professionally made the complaint and was basically ignored. Obfuscation, Password the folder, etc?

Comment: Create your own dev machine. Not sure how you are versioning the WF and IP forms but if they are stored in source control that they will be visible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of your own Dev environment like Marek suggested, you can hide things by keeping them in draft mode - so if you're creating a new sub site, don't check it in (in the case of a publishing site at least) just hit save. You'll still be able to browse to it, however not even site admins will be able to see it.

Same with workflows and Infopath forms - hit save, but don't publish. It makes it incredibly hard to test however, because you will need to publish before you can test it properly.

Sounds like you're in a terrible situation, and I'm sorry to hear it.